# Insert data from 2 different sources into one table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm very new to MySQL and PHP. I have two tables. The first one is `users` which has the information for the site users and the second table is called `SendRequests`.

I want to store the data each user posts (it's like an ad posting site) in the second table where I want the first column to be for the email of the logged-in user so I can find the posts from that user later. This is how I am trying to do it:

Using two `INSERT`s as follows:

```
$query1=" INSERT INTO SendRequests (email) SELECT email FROM users
WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id']."' LIMIT 1";

mysqli_query($link, $query1);

$_SESSION['id']= mysqli_insert_id($link);


$query = "INSERT INTO `SendRequests` (`country`, `city`, `fee`) VALUES
('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['departurecountry'])."',
'".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['departurecity'])."',
'".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['fee'])."')."')
WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id']."'";

mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query to insert data while searching for your email :

```
INSERT INTO SendRequests(email, country, city, fee)
SELECT email, "FR", "Paris", 56.65
FROM SendRequests
WHERE id = 1;
```

This will works if a row with id `1` is already inserted. You can by this way merge your 2 insert in a single one.

So if the SendRequests with id 1 is equal to `anon@host.com`, and you run the query above, you'll have at least 2 rows :

```
ID EMAIL          COUNTRY  CITY    FEE
========================================
1  anon@host.com  US       Florida 150.25
2  anon@host.com  FR       Paris   56.65
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time to answer my question , I tried the code but its not working yet , maybe beacause the second part is from a different table so i tried this:                                                      INSERT INTO SendRequests(email, country, city, fee)
SELECT email, "FR", "Paris", 56.65
FROM user
WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id']."' ;                                                                    and it is not working

Comment: It is working now , i forgot a '' , Thank you soooooooo much for the help man , means a lot

Comment: Glad I could help, if it has solved your issue, do not forget to mark this anwser as solution to let futur viewer see the solution too.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the second query - a spare `."')` towards the end ~ change it to:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `SendRequests` (`country`, `city`, `fee`) VALUES
           ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['departurecountry'])."',
            '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['departurecity'])."',
            '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['fee'])."')
           WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id']."'";
```